# Python - operate on certain elements of a tuple while doing multiple assignment?

Tags: python

Doing something like this,

```
s = "12:00 PM"
hours, s = s.split(':')
hours = int(hours)
```

is there an elegant one-line idiom to perform type conversion on the first element of the tuple before assignment?

Here's one option, but it's rather unpythonic

```
hours, s = (int(w) if w.isdigit() else w for w in s.split(':'))
```

Comment: int(s.split(":")[0]) --like that?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I don't think there's a nice idiom for this, but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: or did you mean while preserving the second half of the tuple assignment as well?

Comment: As you can probably tell from all the answers, no, there is no elegant one-line idiom. The clean approach is exactly what you provided in our question in the first code block.

Comment: This has been asked many times and the answer was and is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a tuple from an in-line lambda function, and call it:

```
hours, rest = (lambda t: (int(t[0]),t[1]))(s.split(':'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
>>> s = "12:00 PM"
>>> hour, the_rest=[(int(x),y) for x,y in [s.split(':')]][0]
>>> hour
12
```

If it does not offend to find the same character twice, you could also do:

```
>>> hour, the_rest=int(s[0:s.find(':')]), s[s.find(':')+1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is already ok. If you don't need the rest of the items:

```
hours = int(s.split(":", 1)[0])
```

Note: `.split()` returns a list, not a tuple.

You could use slicing, to extract the prefix:

```
hours = int(s[:s.index(":")])
```

---

It is possible to bind an object to a new name and use that name on the same line but it is mostly useful for  brain teasers:

```
t = a, *b = t[int(a)] = "0:rest".split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to extract hour

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('12:00 PM', '%H:%M %p').hour
12
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to make some elegant function to do it. Here's example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def cast(*items):
    """
    Usage:
        cast('some', '123')(str, int) -> ['some', 123]
    """
    def to_type(*types):
        return [t(i) if t is not None else i 
                for i, t in zip_longest(items, types)]
    return to_type


s = "12:00 PM"
hours, _ = cast(*s.split(':'))(int)

print(hours, type(hours))  # 12 <class 'int'>
```